# Android app expansion packs

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How would I implement expansion packs on the market? Like if I wanted users to be able to purchase more images, how would I do that and also have the main app recognize and load those images? Are there any tutorials you can point me to? I searched using Google but didn't find anything very specific and beginner friendly. Most were in regards to in app billing but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Google has a whole in-app purchasing API.  Look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) to look for your expansion packs.  The exact way in which you would identify your expansion packs depends on how you're going to use them.

For example, if your expansion packs are runnable in some way - i.e., they all have a main activity - then you'd probably have a custom intent action, and you'd use `PackageManager.queryIntentActivities()` to give you a list of installed activities that can handle that action.

If these expansion packs are providing just resources and not code, you can choose to either have a "dummy" component that you can identify by intent as detailed above - even if you have no intent of ever running it - or you can look for another approach.  For example, if no one but you will be making these expansion packs, you may simply identify them by package name.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledPackages();
for(PackageInfo package : packages) {
    if(package.packageName.startWith("com.myapp.extension.") {
        // found an extension package!
        handleExtensionPackage(package);
    }
}
```

If you need to load a resource from an extension package, you'll need to create a context for that package, look up the resource identifier, and then load the resource.

```
Context extensionContext = createPackageContext(package.packageName, 0);
Resources extensionResources = extensionContext.getResources();
int r_drawable_pic = extensionResources.getIdentifier("drawable/pic", null, package.packageName);
Drawable remotePic = extensionResources.getDrawable(r_drawable_pic);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! +500!! You rock!! That's exactly what I was looking for. One question though, how would I make it so they don't show up in the app drawer?

Comment: only activites with ACTION_MAIN and CATEGORY_LAUNCHER show up in the app drawer.